# Geometric interpretation of the Lie bracket: Sign of the "gap"?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, visualization, lie-derivative

**The short of it:**

Concerning Lie brackets of vector fields: Who's right with the *sign* of the "gap vector"? Does $[V=d/d\mu, W=d/d\lambda]$ point from $A$ to $B$ or from $B$ to $A$?

Adapted from Schutz's "Geometrical methods in mathematical physics":
[image: Interpretation of Lie bracket for general vector fields.]

But in other sources the sign differs, e.g. [Hehl 2007](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.1535):
[image: from https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.1535]

Who is right?

**The long of it:**
I'm reading Bernard Schutz's "Geometrical methods in mathematical physics", which -- being a physicist myself -- strikes a great balance for me between explanatory detail and rigor.

I'd like to prefix my question with some things that I think I understand, so that it's easier for others to point to where I might have erred. I added two figures to illustrate what I'm trying to get to.

I cannot find an answer to my specific question, though I have seen similar arguments as the following posted.

I can understand how vector fields can be seen as operators acting on functions. The coordinate representation of the Lie bracket

$[V, W] = \left(V^j \frac{W^i}{\partial x_j} - W^j \frac{V^i}{\partial x_j} \right)\partial_i$

is clear to me and using the product rule, I can derive the "product rule"

$[fX, gY] = fg[X, Y] + fX(Y) - gY(f)X$.

Schutz describes the geometric interpretation of the Lie bracket by using the exponentiation of vector fields that describe finite motions along integral curves: Let $V = d / d\lambda$ and $W = d / d \mu$ be vector fields. Starting at a point $P$, moving $\Delta \lambda = \epsilon$ along the V curve through $P$ to a point $R$, and then moving $\Delta \mu = \epsilon$ along a W curve, ending at a point $A$. Then start again at $P$, go first $\Delta \mu$ along $W$ and then $\Delta \lambda$ along $V$ ending at a point $B \neq A$. The vector from $A$ to be $B$ is $\epsilon^2[V, W]$, to lowest order in $\varepsilon$, since

$x^i(R) = \exp\left(\epsilon \frac{d}{d\lambda}\right)x^i|_P \\
x^i(A) = \exp\left(\epsilon \frac{d}{d\mu}\right) \exp\left(\epsilon \frac{d}{d\lambda}\right)x^i|_P$

and analogously

$x^i(B) = \exp\left(\epsilon \frac{d}{d\lambda}\right) \exp\left(\epsilon \frac{d}{d\mu}\right)x^i|_P$.

Using the Taylor series of the exponentials yields

$x^i(B) - x^i(A) = \left[\exp\left(\epsilon \frac{d}{d\lambda}\right) \exp\left(\epsilon \frac{d}{d\mu}\right), \exp\left(\epsilon \frac{d}{d\mu}\right) \exp\left(\epsilon \frac{d}{d\lambda}\right)\right]x^i|_P \\
 = \epsilon^2\left[V, W\right]|_P$.

This makes sense to me, the exponentials act from the left on $x^i$ so the rightmost exponential acts first.  You from $P$ to $A$ via $WV$ and you get from $P$ to $B$ via $VW$.

So all of this should be easy to verify with an example, right?

Lets take polar coordinates $(r, \phi)$ in 2d and three vector fields:

$V := \cos(\phi) \partial_x + \sin(\phi) \partial_y = \frac{x}{r} \partial_x + \frac{y}{r} = \partial_r\\
W := -r\sin(\phi) \partial_x + r \cos(\phi) \partial_y = -y \partial_x + x \partial_y = \partial_{\phi}\\
Z := -\sin(\phi) \partial_x +  \cos(\phi) \partial_y = \frac{1}{r} \partial_{\phi}$

The vector fields $V$ and $W$ are the usual ones for polar coordinates and form a coordinate basis, since they commute with each other: $[V, W] = 0$ (just plug in the definition of the Lie bracket and use the product rule for the Lie bracket together with commuting partial derivatives $[\partial_x, \partial_y] = 0$. Ok.

Using the product rule for Lie brackets yet again yields straightforwardly:

$[V, Z] = [V, \frac{1}{r} W] = \frac{1}{r} [V, W] + \frac{\partial r^{-1}}{\partial_r} \partial_\phi = -\frac{1}{r^2} \partial_\phi= -\frac{1}{r} Z \neq 0$

I get the same result by separately computing $V(Z) = ... = 0$ and $Z(V) = \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_\phi$ and again $[V, Z] = -\frac{1}{r^2} \partial_\phi$.

So the vector field $[V, Z]$ points opposite to $\partial_\phi$.

**Finally my question:**
How does this connect to $[V, Z]$ pointing from $A$ to $B$? Following the above reasoning of following the flows, I get to $A$ by following first $V$ and then $Z$, so as an operator it's $ZV$; and I get to $B$ by following first $Z$ and then $V$, so as an operator it's $VZ$. Sketching this for small $\epsilon$ (or large radii so that the circle segments look almost like straight lines), starting at $P = (x=1, y=0)$ results in $B$ being almost directly above $A$, so $\vec B - \vec A = \epsilon^2 [V, Z] + O(\epsilon^4)$ points almost completely in positive $y$ direction. But from my calculations I see that $[V, Z] = - \frac{1}{r^2}\partial_\phi$ so evaluated at $P = (1, 0)$ this yields $-\partial_y$. Exactly opposite of what I expected!

[image: Interpretation of Lie bracket for unit basis vector fields for polar coordinates.]

I can follow the derivation of why the Lie bracket points from $A$ to $B$, but the example yields the opposite!

Where am I going wrong?

Sorry for the rather long post, but I think my question may be unclear without context.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It seems like you hastily assume that Cartesian and polar coordinates must both lead to the same sign. That sign is what it is. What matters is the size of the commutator which is related to curvature.

Comment: I was able to confirm my intuition behind my second sketch by calculating the integral curves of $V$, $W$, and $Z$ and following them in the manner described for infinitesimal parameter times $\Delta t$. As expected, $A = B$ for the fields $V$ and $W$. For $V$ and $Z$, though, $B - A = \Delta t^2 \partial_y + O(\Delta t^3)$.

Comment: Thanks, @KurtG., for your comment. When considering the Lie bracket $[X, Y] = XY - YX$, I can understand that $XY$ and $YX$ depend on the coordinate system, and this is what I see, too, in the example with $V$, $W$, and $Z$. But $[X, Y]$ is a tensor and does not depend on a coordinate system (just like curvature). Computing, for example $[V, Z]$ yields the same result not matter what coordinate system I start with (cartesian or polar). That's all consistent and expected. I still can't solve the sign issue. $[V, Z]|_{P=(1, 0)} = -e_y$ but $B-A = +e_y$. Did I understand your comment correctly?